# How to automatically export a chart from Excel (or Calc) to PNG

Tags: excel, charts, export, openoffice-calc

**The problem:**

I'm working on a web application that exports data from a database to Excel, including a chart, which is the main reason for the export in the first place.

Now I would like for the chart to also be visible on the web page, without the need of exporting the data and opening the downloaded excel file. This could be of course done with JS libraries, but seeing as the chart is quite complicated, I would like to re-use existing export to excel instead or rewriting it all over again, now in JS.

**Desired solution:**

So, this is the best scenario possible: If it was possible to export a chart from excel file to png (or jpg or whatever) without even opeing the excel file, like from a command line or something. Also the generated files open well in OpenOffice, so I could go with that. Then I could just export to excel on server, then export the image from excel, and just send the image to client.

Is something like this even possible? I'm not against a third party program if it would do the trick. If not, what do you think is the next best solution for this scenario?

I have Excel 2016, and I'm generating the excel file with PHPExcel, if that is of any importance.

**Posible solutions:**

Some good options seem to be to [save the document as web page](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/08/27/save-excel-chart-as-image/), but I don't know if you can do that fro mcommand line / without opening the excel UI.

Also the [Open Office API](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API) doesn't look half bad, but I have never used it before, could you export a chart via this API (with Java or something) without opening the Calc UI? I know open office has the --invisible option, that could prove useful.

Comment: (For excel) you could do this via vbscript, if that is an option for you.

Comment: One more question: is this about _opening_ the workbook or about _seeing_ the workbook?

Comment: @Tom I never considered the difference. I guess it's about seeing the workbook. I guess is needs to be opened in one way or another. My main point is i need to export the chart *automaticly*, without single interaction with the UI from the user - since there is no user to interact with UI on the server, where the export needs to happen.

Comment: I'll post an answer in a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, this will export the chart as a .png file, but it opens the excel file (and closes it afterwards), you can try this:

Put it into a `.vbs`-file and run it via console.

```
    Set objXLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set yWkbk = objXLS.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\yourpath\yourfile.xls")
    'Sheet ID can change of course 
    Set yWksht = yWkbk.Sheets(1)
    Set yChart = yWksht.ChartObjects("yourchartname").Chart
    yChart.Export "C:\yourpath\yourfilename.png", "PNG"

    objXLS.Quit
    Set objXLS = Nothing
```

Comment: That seems nice, but I can't find how to run a visual basic file. I'm using windows 10. The official download site just doesnt work, it doesnt dowload anything https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=10019

Comment: I don't use Win10 but afaik this should work. Also the the download link works fine for me. You can try this: http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/cant-run-vbscript-from-batch-file/30277.html or just create the `.vbs`-file, paste the code into the file, save and close. Run via doubleclick.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the API.  This command worked for me:

```
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe" -convert-to png "Untitled 1.ods" -headless
```

For a discussion see: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/

Comment: Thanks, this does export the chart, that is nice, but a few things (like the legend) are missing, where in opening the file with libre office shows the legend just fina.

Comment: That's strange, it showed the legend when I tried it.  Maybe a bug in your particular version of LO?  Mine is 5.1.0.3.  Also I used the .ods format, where it sounds like you are using an Excel format.