# Export Excel Chart from Open XMl Excel asimage wihtou Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, excel-charts

I am trying to export chart that was already generated as a excel file using open XML. Is there a way i could export the chart present in each sheet of excel file without using Microsoft interop libraries or any other paid 3rd party tools ?

I need this to be hosted in a server, and wont be able to buy any 3rd party tools. 
Kindly help me here.

Is this approach safe ?
[How to automatically export a chart from Excel (or Calc) to PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787803/how-to-automatically-export-a-chart-from-excel-or-calc-to-png)

Comment: found a related thread, seems this is not possible to do via Open XML
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9aaa8adc-df2c-4ab2-8eec-739265a97019/save-chart-as-image-by-using-open-xml?forum=oxmlsdk

Comment: Is it possible to create Charts that look with style that looks like styles we apply in Ms Excel ?.